# What is the correct name to give to a taxonomy term page template file?

Tags: taxonomy-terms, 7

I have a taxonomy term page, which is not a view. It just lists all the content for the taxonomy. I would like to customize this page, and I have tried all permutations and combinations of names for the template file. The template file just won't work.
I have tried page--taxonomy--term--5.tpl.php, page_*taxonomy*_term__5.tpl.php.

What is the right filename to give to the template file, in this case?

I am using Drupal 7.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that template.php file also needed a preprocess function for this to work:

```
function THEMENAME_preprocess_page(&$variables) {
 if ( arg(0) == 'taxonomy' && arg(1) == 'term' ) {
   $term = taxonomy_term_load(arg(2));
   $variables['theme_hook_suggestions'][] = 'page__taxonomy__term__' . $term->tid;
    }
}
```

then page--taxonomy--term--5.tpl.php works for a specific term

Comment: Thx, keva. That worked!

Answer (score 3):

I use, for instance,

`page--taxonomy--term--6.tpl.php`

Make sure you **clear the cache** in Configuration > Performance > Clear all caches after creating your template.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the theme developer module to find any template name or theme function. Just enable the module and point and click on the thing you like to theme differently.